# Why do I need absolute convergence to prove $\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm reading Conway's [Complex Analysis book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387903283) and on page 38 he said we can manipulate the power series because they are absolute convergent:

[image]

Let's see:

Conway defines

$$\cos z=1-z^2/2+z^4/24-\ldots$$

So, we know

$$e^{iz}=1+iz-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z^3i}{6}+\frac{z^4}{24}+\frac{z^5i}{120}\ldots$$
$$e^{-iz}=1-iz-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3i}{6}+\frac{z^4}{24}-\frac{z^5i}{120}+\ldots$$

Now, lets call $e^{iz}=\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)$ and $e^{-iz}=\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n'=\lim_{n\to \infty}(b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_n)$.

Then, we have

$$\cos z=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1/2(a_1+b_1)+1/2(a_2+b_2)+\ldots1/2(a_n+b_n))=\lim_{n\to \infty}(((1/2)a_1+(1/2)a_2+\ldots+(1/2)a_n))+((1/2)b_1+(1/2)b_2+\ldots+(1/2)b_n)))=1/2\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)+1/2\lim_{n\to \infty}(b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_n)=(1/2)e^{iz}+(1/2)e^{-iz}=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$

I think I didn't use the fact the series $e^{iz}$ and $e^{-iz}$ are absolute convergent. Where am I wrong? what am I missing?

**EDIT**

Note that I'm using commutativity only in the finite case:

$$\lim\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k+b_k)=\lim((\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)+(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k))=\lim(s_n+s_n')=\lim s_n+\lim s_n'$$.

I need help

Thanks!

Comment: If this approach bothers you, you can use the fact that you know $\sin'=\cos$ and $\cos'=-\sin$ together with the chain rule to prove that $\sin^2+\cos^2$ is constant. To prove that it is equal to $1$ is a mere substitution.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo What bothers me is the fact I didn't understand why do we need the Riemann rearrangement theorem in this case. Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: I agree with you that you do not need absolute convergence. But maybe I wrong. Even if you do need, the text is rather vague.

Comment: yes, besides if we look closer I'm using commutativity only in the finite case which I'm allowed to do.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo thank you for the remark

Comment: Sorry, I made the remark, but upon looking the question yet again I'm confused. You indeed define the $a_i,b_i$, but in the way they are defined, why does the first equality after what you put after "Then" holds?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo it's the definition of $\cos z=1-z^2/2+z^4/24-\ldots$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33518/discussion-between-aloizio-macedo-and-user42912).

Answer (score 1):

[Riemann rearrangement theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)

The statement 
$\lim_{n\to \infty}(((1/2)a_1+(1/2)a_2+\ldots+(1/2)a_n))+((1/2)b_1+(1/2)b_2+\ldots+(1/2)b_n)))=1/2\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)+1/2\lim_{n\to \infty}(b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_n)$

is valid only due to Riemann rearrangement theorem, as the first limit is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Why do I need this theorem? I didn't commute the terms of the series

Comment: @Suhail This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @user42912 Well, when you say $$\lim_n \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k+b_k) = \lim_n \sum_{k=1}^n a_k + \lim_n \sum_{k=1}^n b_k$$ you are somehow commuting the terms

Comment: See $\lim\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k+b_k)=\lim((\sum a_k)+(\sum b_k))=\lim(s_n+s_n')=\lim s_n+\lim s_n'$. Note that $s_n$ and $s_n'$ are sequences. Where am I using absolute convergence? I commute the terms only in the finite case.

Comment: @user42912 To say that $\lim(s_n+s_n')=\lim s_n+\lim s_n'$ you need to be sure that the later _exist_. One way to ensure it is the absolute convergence, otherwise you have to work it out somehow.

Comment: Of course the limits of $s_n$ and $s_n'$ do exist. They are the definition of $e^{iz}$ and $e^{-iz}$ respectively. Otherwise I'm missing something.

Comment: @user42912 If you define the complex exponential as a complex series then you have to work out the convergence. How do you ensure it?

Comment: @A.G. Conway has already proved the convergence of the exponential (page 32) and of the cosine power series (page 38) . So we can consider the convergence of the exponential and of the cosine power series as something already proved.

Comment: @user42912 Normally (the easiest) is to prove that the complex series is absolutely convergent by estimating it by the series for $e^{|z|}$. If this is the case in Conway then the absolute convergence is implicitly used here.

Comment: @A.G. To sum up, we don't need of the absolute convergence in my question's case.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you don't need absolute convergence. At most what you are doing is eliminating zero-terms from the series in its usual ordering, and this does not need absolute convergence to do.